# how to select image from Device and it's path in android Studio

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I need to select image from device and it's full path
But I get null value.. this is my Code
any suggestions

```
    private void openPicture() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            Toast.makeText(this, ""+selectedImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {

    if( uri == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if( cursor != null ){
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return path;
    }
    return uri.getPath();

}
```

it's return **Null** value. I need **selected image Path**.

Comment: `selectedImageUri` is null or you get the uri. You can use the uri. why do you need path

Comment: **Raghunandan** i need result like this . **"/storage/emulated/0/Download/image.jpg"**

Comment: why do you need it. you get a uri and you can use that to upload if need be. read https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html

Comment: 'SelectedImageUri' will return like this **content://com.android.providers.media.documents/documents/image**

Comment: it works as expected. You need to use the uri to do what you intend to do. read the link mentioned in above comment

Comment: @Raghunandan , can i show that image in **imageview** from **SelectedImageUri**

Comment: yes you can  `InputStream inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(your uri)` adn then
                `if (inputStream != null) { Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)}` and then `photo.setImageBitmap(img)`